# Is it possible to get SMS texts for tweets from a specific user that match certain words?

Tags: twitter, search, sms

I know that you can send an SMS text from Twitter for all tweets that you get from a specific user. But is it possible to only send texts when a tweet is from a specific user and that also match specific keywords.

I used to use Stringify to do this for me, but they disabled their app starting in June.

I have tried IFTTT and while it does allow me to do this there is a significant lag.  I get the texts anywhere between 12 and 24 hours later and some times I don't even get a text.

Does anyone know of a way to do this through Twitter, I already have the Twitter search string that returns what I want, or through some other tool or app?

Thank you for any help or suggestions you can share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[Zapier](https://zapier.com/)** to automate a task beginning with a Twitter search trigger and ending with an SMS to your mobile. It won't run in real-time , however, [they commit](https://zapier.com/help/triggers/) to run triggers every 5 to 15 min. (shorter for payed version).

You can have the SMS `action` part linked with a twitter search `trigger`. Zapier will run the search trigger every 15 min. If a tweet or tweets get caught in the search, Zapier will send you an SMS about it with links to the tweets.